# Permission in website

Tags: c#, .net

i am developing a small project in my localhost.
But i am a little problem, i have this ;

```
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="Login.aspx"/>
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
  <location path="RecoverPassword.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

but when i go to login.aspx (i have a link to go to RecoverPassword), and when i click it always go to login.aspx.
What i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me like you're doing it right. Only thing I'd guess is that somewhere you've misspelled something - try double-checking that the link really takes you to `RecoverPassword.aspx`.

Comment: I just copy the name of the page.

Comment: and still happend the same :S

Comment: if i in vs2008 select the page and then choose view in browser it works, but if a enter in login page and then the recover page, it goes to the login

Comment: What exactly is in your Login page that sends you to RecoverPassword? I'd expect `<a href="RecoverPassword.aspx">Recover Password</a>`. And when you click it, do you just stay at `Login.aspx` or is is something like `Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fRecoverPassword.aspx`?

Comment: just see what is wrong LOL grrrrrrrrrrrrrrr tks joe :P ... when copy here, see the name of the page misspelled :p

Comment: No problem. I do that all the time - drives me nuts. I'll spend an hour looking at all the complicated things that could be wrong, and turns out to be something simple.